# How to use inner join of persistence js

Tags: sqlite, cordova, persistent

I am new programmer student, now i develop mobile app with phonegap. So I use sqlite and persistence js.but I don't know  how to write "inner join" in persistence js function.  Hope all of you help me.

Comment: Without seeing any code could be hard to give an accurate answer. Here is a link to page explaining JOINS in WebSQL: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/joins/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation:

```
https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs
```

Some text from it:

The methods to define relationships to other entities:

```
EntityName.hasMany(property, Entity, inverseProperty)
```

defines a 1:N or N:M relationship (depending on the inverse property).

```
EntityName.hasOne(property, Entity)
```

defines a 1:1 or N:1 relationship.

If an object has a hasOne relationship to another which has not yet been fetched from the database (e.g. when prefetch wasn't used), you can fetch in manually using fetch. When the property object is retrieved the callback function is invoked with the result, the result is also cached in the entity object itself.

```
obj.fetch(prop, callback)
```